# Interpreting bidding by partners

Tags: bridge, bidding

RHO: 1C --> LHO: 1S --> RHO: 2D

Does this mean 4-4 in clubs/diamonds, or 5-4 in clubs diamonds. Is it a reverse? (e.g.18+ pts?).

Assuming opponents play SAYC.

Answer (score 3):

- Definitely a reverse, say 15-16+ HCP + distributional values.
- Promises 5+ clubs.
- Can be a "waiting reverse" with only 3 diamonds to elicit more information from partner, with either 3 hearts or 6+ clubs.

The point to a "waiting reverse" is when opener has multiple options for a non-ideal bid, and wishes to set the denomination **after** responder rebids. It should be done only in a suit below 2 of responder's suit, unless opener is stronger than a minimum reverse. As noted it is often done with 3 of responder's suit to see if responder can rebid it. It often implies slam interest, as the extra information communicated may be of more use to the defence in merely a game contract.

With a minimum reverse, opener must be able to retreat to either 3 of responder's suit or 3NT if the reverse suit is raised.

Comment: Thank you for thorough explanation. so answering higher ranked suit on higher level definitely means reverse, right? How would you go if you had minimum opening points (12pts), 4C-4D-4H-1S, opened 1C, partner responded 1S (forcing). You can't show 2D due to minimum opening points & you can't bid 1nt.

Comment: Open 1D instead of 1C. If you can't handle all possible responses by partner, then you don't have an opening 1-bid.

Comment: Rephrasing slightly: Open 1D instead of 1C. If you can't *rebid over* all possible *forcing* responses by partner, then you don't have an opening 1-bid